# How to refresh a div's content on ajax success

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w16Gu.png)

How can I refresh a `div`'s *like-count* when the ajax succeeds?

**Problem:** When I click `dislike`, I need to refresh the page just can see the result change.

**Question:** How can I do this to immediately display the result?

Comment: show your code.*ajax

Comment: get refrence from this http://kimjoyfox.com/using-ajax-to-reload-only-a-div/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
success:function(response) {
    $("#divID").html(response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Empty the `div` on AJAX `success`

```
success: function(response){
    $('.your-div-class').empty();
    //then append your result or change the style 
    $('.your-div-class').append('html');   
}
```

if you want to change the style of the `div` you can check this link,

http://www.kirupa.com/html5/setting_css_styles_using_javascript.htm

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell exactly what you are looking for when you don't provide any code or detailed examples, but I hope this helps in some way.

You can use ajax's **success** function to change the DOM element's text value.

Example:

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="likes">
    <button id="like-button">like</button>
    <button id="dislike-button">dislike</button>

    <span id="like-count">0</span>
    <span id="dislike-count">0</span>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#like-button').on('click', function() {
        updateLikes ('like');
    });

    $('#dislike-button').on('click', function() {
        updateLikes ('dislike');
    });

    function updateLikes (type) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            async: true,
            url: 'server.php',
            data: {command: type},
            success: function(data) {
                number = parseInt(data);
                var currentLike;
                var span;
                if (type == 'like') {
                    span = $('#like-count');
                    currentLike = parseInt(span.text());    
                } else {
                    span = $('#dislike-count');
                    currentLike = parseInt(span.text()); 
                }
                span.empty();
                currentLike += number;
                span.text(currentLike.toString());
            }
        });
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What the above does is once someone clicks the like/dislike button, it will run a function on your server that updates the number of likes in your database. When finished, the server will return an integer which is then added to the current number of likes. This is all done asynchronously so you won't have to wait for a response from the server before continuing with the rest of your script. It also updates the number without having to refresh the page.